# Probability of getting even number of tails after flipping n coins

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I was first asked the probability of getting an even number of heads ($P_n$) supposedly after flipping $n$ fair coins. I calculated that to be $1/2$.

Using this information, I don't know how to solve the same question if the coins are biased such that the probability of getting heads is $x$ and tails is $1-x$. My main confusion is that I don't know how to tackle or isolate $x$ with unfair/biased coins, and thus don't know what formula to generate for the new $P_n$ with this condition.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: katyf, you cannot just deface your posts like this. After an answer has been posted, the decision is no longer yours alone. If you feel there is something wrong with the question, you can report it at a dedicated chatroom like [C.R.U.D.E](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) where users with a lot of experience will take a look at it. If they think the question is a poor fit for the site, they may close and/or delete it. Because you are personally involved, you should not be the one making the decision.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p$ be the probability of getting a head, and let $q=1-p$ be the probability of getting a tail. Let $p_n$ be the probability of getting an even number of heads in $n$ flips, and let $q_n=1-p_n$ be the probability of getting an odd number of heads in $n$ flips. Then

$$p_n=p_{n-1}q+q_{n-1}p\;:$$

to get an even number of heads in $n$ flips you must either get an even number of heads in $n-1$ flips and then get a tail, or get an odd number of heads in $n-1$ flips and then get a head. Rewrite this to get rid of $q$ and $q_n$:

$$p_n=p_{n-1}(1-p)+(1-p_{n-1})p=p_{n-1}(1-2p)+p\;.$$

This is a simple first order linear recurrence that can be solved in many ways. One simple way is to ‘unwind’ it:

$$\begin{align*}
p_n&=(1-2p)p_{n-1}+p\\
&=(1-2p)\big((1-2p)p_{n-2}+p\big)+p\\
&=(1-2p)^2p_{n-2}+(1-2p)p+p\\
&=(1-2p)^2\big((1-2p)p_{n-3}+p\big)+(1-2p)p+p\\
&=(1-2p)^3p_{n-3}+(1-2p)^2p+(1-2p)p+p\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=(1-2p)^kp_{n-k}+p\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(1-2p)^\ell\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=(1-2p)^np_0+p\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(1-2p)^\ell\\
&\overset{*}=(1-2p)^n+p\frac{1-(1-2p)^n}{1-(1-2p)}\\
&=(1-2p)^n+\frac12\big(1-(1-2p)^n\big)\\
&=\frac12\big(1+(1-2p)^n\big)
\end{align*}$$

At the starred step I used the fact that $p_0=1$: the number of heads when no coins have been tossed is $0$, which is even.

You can see that this is always $\frac12$ if $p=\frac12$, is always $1$ if $p=0$ (so that you always have $0$ heads), and alternates between $1$ and $0$ if $p=1$, since in that case you have a head on every throw and therefore have an even number of heads if and only if $n$ is even. Finally, you can check that if $0<p<1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n=\frac12$.